# Find and change the color of text in Label

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the label color to RED when (Not Recommended) is a part of Label. Is there any way to find the text from Label and change the color of it. I don't want to use a class for all and to change them.

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <title> Label Color Change </title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="imgDisplay">Do you want to Display Image:<br>(Not Recommended)</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="imgUrl" name="imgUrl" type="checkbox" checked=False>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="linkInsert"> Add a Link on the top :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input for="chckLink" name="chckLink" type="checkbox">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="userDetails"> Wish to take User Details :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input for="userDetail" name="userDetail" type="checkbox">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: tried anything..? If yes show your code..

Comment: try to use `contains` in `javascript` and solve the issue.

Comment: @Sudhir, No I haven't tried anything. I was searching net for the same. But failed so posted it here.
@Ullas will try working with `contains` . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way, that will work on any browser and won't rely on any library is to loop through all the labels on the page, look for the text in them, and paint them red.

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Not Recommended') !== -1) {
        labels[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x2aHm/)**

---

Although using a class is the correct course of action. These labels have something in common, they are all not recommended. In fact a better course of action can be seen **[in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/x2aHm/2/)**, where the Not Recommended is added on its own with CSS.

Comment: Thank you @Second This is helpful though ! Yes I am not using jquery in my html page yet. So this is a good solution and works on browsers as well.

Comment: @SuburbSanyaasi please see my recent edit, using an HTML class **is** the right solution, and I hope you use that instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### [Find fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ern9V/1/)

**JS (Uses jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("label:contains(Not Recommended)").css("color", "red");
});
```

Comment: Please don't suggest jQuery on something that can clearly be easily done without jQuery. Also, OP has not mentioned that he was using jQuery.

Comment: @SecondRikudo:But `javascript` tag is there. But it will be easy to use with jquery rite. So no need of downvoting.

Comment: @SecondRikudo:Even OP congratulated me for my work. That solved his/her issue too.

Comment: And yet on a comment on my answer, he said that he indeed didn't use jQuery. So OP needs to make up his mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the function:

```
window.find(text)
```

where your text will be '(Not Recommended)' in your case

As per browser support this function works on chrome, firefox and safari.

For IE you need to use the findText method of the TextRange object for similar functionality

Comment: I'm not sure about the browser support for that, but it doesn't look promising.

Comment: @v31 will try and revert back in sometime. Thank you so much.